# An error was encountered with the requested page after user sign up

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I am new to AWS cognito. I have a requirements to manage users though AWS cognito.

1. Users can sign themselves up
2. I am using hosted UI to achieve this.
   https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pools-app-integration.html
3. Only admin can confirm user from AWS console.
4. User is getting created with `Unconfirmed` status (expected).

Everything works as expected, but at the time of sign up, hosted UI responds with "An error was encountered with the requested page".

I don't want user to be auto approved and hence not invoking pre sign up lambda.

Please find attached image [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vkySu.png).

Is there any way I can display custom message like "User is created, please contact admin for user confirmation" ??

Thank you .

Answer (score 0):

The issue is occuring probably because you chose `Allow users to sign themselves up` and did not chose any verification type - `No verification`.
Choose `Only allow administrators to create users` or any verification type to avoid this issue.